# Input range c переключением между заданными точками

Tags: javascript, html, rangeslider

Посоветуйте плагин (желательно на чистом js) который позволяет создать ползунок с точками, расположенными на разном расстоянии друг от друга. Вот как на рисунке ниже.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не думаю что вам нужен какой-то плагин. Подобный ползунок можно реализовать с помощью `<input type="range">`, `<datalist>` и немного `js`.

В `datalist` внесите необходимые значения, а `js` не позволит выбрать значения, которых нет в `datalist`.


Подробнее о `<input type="range">` можете прочитать [здесь](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/range).

```js
var input = document.querySelector('input');
var values = Array.from(input.list.options).map(o => o.value);
var prevValue = input.value;
input.addEventListener('input', function () {
    if (!values.includes(this.value)) {
        var index = values.findIndex(v => Number(v) > Number(this.value));
        if (Number(this.value) < Number(prevValue)) {
            index--;
        }
        this.value = values[index];
    }
    prevValue = this.value;
});
```

```html
<input type="range" list="tickmarks" value="0" step="1">
<datalist id="tickmarks">
  <option value="0"/>
  <option value="20"/>
  <option value="77"/>
  <option value="100"/>
</datalist>
```

Comment: Вот только данное решение работает криво даже с JS. В даталисте указанно 4 "засечки", а ползунок проходит 6.

Comment: @CbIPoK2513 Ползунок проходит 6 засечек, но выбрать можно только 4.

Comment: @Vladimir Ваше решение интересное, и симпатично мне. Но ползунок не перескакивает с 20 на 80 как необходимо

Comment: @Vladimir у Вас вполне рабочее решение, только замените событие `onChange` на `onInput` - должно перестать фиксировать промежуточные положения.

Comment: @UModeL да, спасибо, исправил ответ

Comment: @Vladimir Спасибо, теперь работает как задумано. Но я заметил проблему доступности. С клавиатуры можно двинуть ползунок только в одну сторону, в обратную уже нельзя. Пробовал выставить шаг в значение 1, но работает не корректно.

Comment: @FlapJack исправил ответ, теперь с помощью клавиатуры можно двигать ползунок в 2 стороны.

Comment: @Vladimir Спасибо всё работает. Но вот только когда я добавляю значение к примеру 77, вместо 80, ползунок начинает сбиваться. Т.е с целыми значениями всё ок, но вот когда нужно задать точное, что то идет не так.

Comment: @FlapJack нужно поменять атрибут `step` у инпута на 1